# Handling About:Blank / No IP Address

Tags: windows, sockets, visual-c++

I'm running code to get the URL and IP of the current webpage.  This all works fine until About:Blank shows up and it halts my code cold.  The problem is that About:Blank returns no IP address and that is the problem.  How can I keep this running even if there is no IP address.  Yhis where it stops.

```
ppaddr2 = (int**)pHostEnt2->h_addr_list;
sockAddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = **ppaddr2;
addr2 = inet_ntoa(sockAddr2.sin_addr);
```

The relevant code...

```
BSTR bstr;
pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
std::wstring wsURL;
wsURL = bstr;

size_t DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"://");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
    {
    wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + DSlashLoc + 3);
    }
DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"www.");
if (DSlashLoc == 0)
    {
    wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + 4);
    }
DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"/");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
    {
    wsURL.erase(DSlashLoc);
    }
   wprintf(L"\n   Current Website URL: %s", wsURL.c_str());

int Newlength = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
std::string NewLogURL(Newlength+1, 0); 
int Newresult = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, &NewLogURL[0],Newlength+1,  NULL, NULL);

HOSTENT *pHostEnt2;
int  **ppaddr2;
SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr2;
pHostEnt2 = gethostbyname(NewLogURL.c_str());

ppaddr2 = (int**)pHostEnt2->h_addr_list;
sockAddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = **ppaddr2;
addr2 = inet_ntoa(sockAddr2.sin_addr);

printf("\n   Current Website IP:%s", addr2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what rushman said, you could also validate that the URL starts with "http:" or "https:" before processing it.

Also, you should NOT be stripping out the "www." portion.  Everything between "://" and the next "/" is the hostname.  Resolve it as-is, DNS will handle it fine.  In fact, if you strip it off, you can get different results.  For example, "yahoo.com" resolves to "98.139.180.149" but "www.yahoo.com" resolves to "72.30.2.43".  The browser is not going to strip off the "www.", so you should not, either.

Try this:

```
BSTR bstr;
pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
std::wstring wsURL(bstr, SysStringLen(bstr));
SysFreeString(bstr);

std::wstring wsHost;

size_t DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"://");
if (DSlashLoc != std::wstring::npos)
{
    DSlashLoc += 3;

    size_t DSlashLoc2 = wsURL.find(L"/", DSlashLoc);
    if (DSlashLoc2 != std::wstring::npos)
      wsHost = wsURL.substr(DSlashLoc, DSlashLoc2 - DSlashLoc);
    else
      wsHost = wsURL.substr(DSlashLoc);
}

if (wsHost.empty())
{
    printf("\n   Unknown Website Host");
}
else
{
    wprintf(L"\n   Website Host: %s", wsHost.c_str());

    std::string sHost;
    int Newlength = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsHost.c_str(), wsHost.length(), NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
    if (Newlength > 0)
    {
        sHost.resize(Newlength);
        WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsHost.c_str(), wsHost.length(), &sHost[0], Newlength, NULL, NULL);
    }

    HOSTENT *pHostEnt2 = gethostbyname(sHost.c_str());
    if (!pHostEnt2)
    {
        printf("\n   Unknown Website IP");
    }
    else if (pHostEnt2->h_addrtype != AF_INET)
    {
        printf("\n   Website does not use IPv4 addresses");
    }
    else
    {
        for (char **addr = pHostEnt2->h_addr_list; *addr != NULL; ++addr)
        {
            printf("\n   Website IP: %s", inet_ntoa(* (struct in_addr *) *addr));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That, my friend is a VERY useful piece of information!  I am just stripping it off for my database records. I can do that later...

Comment: Thank you.  I'm getting three undefineds  DSlashPos, inaddr and NewLength.  Just two now, typo on Newlength.

Comment: Added this #pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib") and it works...must have gotten removed during many revisons!  Now I'm getting like 6 IP addresses for google as opposed to one, I was hoping to stay with one as I am comparing that IP address that comes in on the several packets I am getting against the current webpage.

Comment: Remy, Thank yoy so very much for your help!  Is there a way to compare a list of IP's to one IP?

Comment: You have to compare them at a time.  Either do a simple string comparison, or convert them to their numeric/binary formats (which would be more reliable) and do a byte comparison.

Answer (score 1):

gethostbyname returns NULL if it cannot find a DNS entry. Just check for that and output a suitable message

Comment: Thank you. I'm kinda new to this.  I am getting about:blank returned but its grinding to a halt because there is no IP address for about:blank.  How would I do this? Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are not checking to see if `gethostbyname()` returns a NULL pointer, you need to do so, like rushman said.  You also need to check if the first entry of `pHostEnt2->h_addr_list` is NULL as well before using it.  Better, you should be looping through the entire `pHostEnt2->h_addr_list` list, as a hostname may have multiple IPs associated with it.  If you want to `connect()` to a hostname, you should be trying all of the available IPs until one succeeds.

Comment: Right direction or not?         if (pHostEnt2 == NULL);
  {
  addr2 = "0.0.0.0";
  }

Comment: I'm using a packet sniffer and it seems that the current website comew back with one IP address at a time.  I know a an URL can have several IP's but isn't only one used at a time.  Sorry, but like I said, new to all of this.

Comment: The packet sniffer (winpcap?) will only return IP information of the current connection. So only one at a time, yes.